# Passing context to serializer from Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Viewset with get_serializer_context method

```
   class UserRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
       serializer_class = UserProfilePageSerializer

       def get_serializer_context(self):
           context = super(UserRetrieveView, self).get_serializer_context()
           context.update({'room' : self.get_object().room_set.all()})
           print(context['room'])
           return context
```

And now I want to put this context to my serializer :

```
    class UserProfilePageSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'name','bio']
```

Honestly I have no idea how to do this. I would really appreciate any help or even some clue

Comment: What's not working? It should already be done by what you have right now. You can access the context inside the serializer using `self.context`

Comment: I don't see added context in my response. I see only fields from serializer,  I don't know how to add this context to serializer to display it in my response like rest of fields

Comment: You could use a [serializer method field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) that returns something from your context

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
   queryset = User.objects.all()
   permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
   serializer_class = UserProfilePageSerializer

   def get_serializer_context(self):
       context = super(UserRetrieveView, self).get_serializer_context()
       context.update({'room' : self.get_object().room_set.all()})
       print(context['room'])
       return context

   def get_serializer(self):
       return self.get_serializer_class()(**self.get_serializer_context())
```

For some reason, this should work, I never checked why but usually something like this, it also happens with form kwargs.

Comment: I don't see added context in my response. I see only fields from serializer, I don't know how to add this context to serializer to display it in my response like rest of fields